# Disable wonky touchscreen on HP Spectre x360

Tags: touchscreen

I have a Spectre with a touchscreen which inevitably registers phantom touches after running for a while. I've searched this forum and found several "Disable Touchscreen" entries, but none seem to work on my machine.

When I try `xinput disable {touch screen id}` I get `WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.`

I've also tried the method of editing `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf` to add `Option "Ignore" "on"` or `MatchIsTouchscreen "off"` and those don't seem to work either.

Does anyone have any other ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu jeffedsell! I think the clue is in the warning: the solutions you've found were for machines with Xorg, and it looks like they don't work the same way with Xwayland. Quoting from the question at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/569265/275183, "disabling an Xwayland device with xinput does not disable the device in Wayland-native applications". So your question is really "what's the equivalent of `xinput --disable` for Wayland?". Also, it might be helpful if you add some more details about your system.

Comment: Using `evtest --grab` (see https://forum.manjaro.org/t/disable-keyboard-in-gnome-wayland/94661 for details) sounds promising, though a bit hacky.  I'd submit as an answer, but I'm running Xorg, so I can't confirm it would work for you. Experiment, and if it's successful, please submit as an answer.

Comment: Well, thanks. I tried it and it does work -- presumably I could run this command at startup, but I see why it's hacky. I'm browsing the Ubuntu wiki regarding Wayland, but it's very much over my head.

Comment: ![Machine specs](https://imgur.com/a/b46rZoH)